# Use Querysets and JSON correctly in API View

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to write my custom API view and I am struggling a bit with querysets and JSON. It shouldn't be that complicated but I am stuck still. Also I am confused by some strange behaviour of the loop I coded.

Here is my view:

```
@api_view()
def BuildingGroupHeatYear(request, pk, year):

    passed_year = str(year)
    building_group_object = get_object_or_404(BuildingGroup, id=pk)
    buildings = building_group_object.buildings.all()

    for item in buildings:
        demand_heat_item = item.demandheat_set.filter(year=passed_year).values('building_id', 'year', 'demand')


    print(demand_heat_item)
    print(type(demand_heat_item)

    return Response(demand_heat_item))
```

Ok so this actually gives me back exactly what I want. Namely that:

```
{'building_id': 1, 'year': 2019, 'demand': 230.3}{'building_id': 1, 'year': 2019, 'demand': 234.0}
```

Ok, great, but why? Shouldn't the data be overwritten each time the loop goes over it?

Also when I get the type of the demand_heat_item I get back a queryset `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

But this is an API View, so I would like to get a JSON back. SHouldn't that throw me an error?

And how could I do this so I get the same data structure back as a JSON?

It tried to rewrite it like this but without success because I can't serialize it:

```
@api_view()
def BuildingGroupHeatYear(request, pk, year):

    passed_year = str(year)
    building_group_object = get_object_or_404(BuildingGroup, id=pk)
    buildings = building_group_object.buildings.all()

         demand_list = []

    for item in buildings:
        demand_heat_item = item.demandheat_set.filter(year=passed_year).values('building_id', 'year', 'demand')
        demand_list.append(demand_heat_item)

    json_data = json.dumps(demand_list)

    return Response(json_data)
```

I also tried with JSON Response and Json decoder.

But maybe there is a better way to do this?

Or maybe my question is formulated clearer like this: How can I get the data out of the loop, and return it as a JSON

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Also, I tried the following:

```
 for item in buildings:
        demand_heat_item = item.demandheat_set.filter(year=passed_year).values('building_id', 'year', 'demand')

    json_data = json.dumps(list(demand_heat_item))

    return Response(json_data)
```

that gives me this weird response that I don't really want:

```
"[{\"building_id\": 1, \"year\": 2019, \"demand\": 230.3}, {\"building_id\": 1, \"year\": 2019, \"demand\": 234.0}]"
```

Comment: Your first view can't be giving that response. But in any case you shouldn't be doing any of this. You should use a serializer to determine what data to return. Then your view can be a simple generic view with no custom code.

Comment: But it is giving me that response ;) I promise.... Really, I shouldn't?! Is that bad practice? The thing is that I want to have an API view which is not connected to my models... I want to send a year and filter my data according to this year

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: that *is* connected to your models, it's just filtering them by year.

Comment: But also please show what you are doing to print these responses and find their types. As I say, the first output is impossible, unless you are simply printing within the loop.

Comment: Yes you are right it is connected to my models.... But how can I filter them via an incoming request in a serializer if I use generic views?? I updated my question with print statements. And I am not printing within the loop. That's why I am confused

Comment: But by printing the content and the type within the view itself, you will get a queryset because that is what you assigned. It is the job of DRF itself, once you have returned the response, to convert it to JSON. You do not need to do it manually. If you requested that view in your browser or via Postman, you would get JSON.

Comment: Ah yes ok I understand, that makes sense. Thank you!!.... Still it shouldn't be giving me that data in the first place....

Comment: Is it very bad doing it like this?